# passing up multiple attributes in yacc/bison

Tags: parsing, attributes, bison, yacc

In order to handle the grammar rule:

```
type            : ARRAY '[' integer_constant RANGE integer_constant ']' OF stype { $$ = $8 }
                | stype { $$ = $1 }
                ;
```

I need to pass up the type attribute (as I'm doing now) but I also need to pass up the range of the array in order to check array bounds.
I've tried all kinds of ways to use a struct in order to achieve something like:

```
type            : ARRAY '[' integer_constant RANGE integer_constant ']' OF stype { $$.type = $8; $$.range[0] = $3; $$.range[1] = $5; }
                | stype { $$.type = $1 }
                ;
```

But everything leads to errors and segfaults and I'm having a tough time finding the correct way to handle this

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance.

parse.y: http://pastebin.com/XUUqG35s

Answer (score 2):

`type` and `stype` are declared to be the `attr` member of the union, which is of type `node*`. Consequently, in the context of an action for either of these non-terminals, `$$` will be replaced with something like `x.attr` (that's just an illustration, don't take it *too* literally.). Similarly in the first action, `$8` will be replaced with something like `yystack[top-8].attr`, because $8 also has the tag `attr`, being an `stype`.

So `$$.type` (or, indeed, `$$.<anything>`) must be a syntax error. `attr` is a pointer so it could be that `$$-><something>` is correct but I can't tell without seeing the definition of `node`.

Also, in the `stype` rules, you set, eg., `$$ = "INT"`, but `$$` is of type `node*`, not `char*` (unless, of course, `node` is a typedef for `char`, but that seems wrong.) It seems likely that eventually that will result in a segfault, when you later treat the value as a pointer to a `node`.

It's really not clear to me what you think `$$.range` might mean. Maybe you need to show more of your headers.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to rici's answer and more directly answering the question in your title, multiple attributes are typically passed through a `struct`, so if you'd change the value associated with the `type` non-terminal to for example `ctype` (`%type <ctype> type`) and `stype` to `type` (`%type <type> stype`) (which I think was your intention) and then add the following to your `%union`

```
struct { int is_array, low, high; char * type; } ctype;
```

then you can change the definition of the `type` non-terminal to

```
type
:    ARRAY '[' integer_constant RANGE integer_constant ']' OF stype
     { $$.is_array = 1; $$.low = $3; $$.high = $5; $$.type = $8; }
|    stype
     { $$.is_array = 0; $$.low = $$.high = -1; $$.type = $1; }
;
```

Of course more changes have to be made to correctly handle the new `ctype`, but this is typically the way to propagate multiple attributes up the parser stack.